# How to LEFT JOIN on when columns have the same name

Tags: php, mysql

The title is a bit confusing, hopefully it is clear what I am trying to do from my query. I thought I understood joins, clearly not, here is my $query:

```
     SELECT DATE(T0.timestamp),
            SUM(T0.total_responses), 
            SUM(T0.responses), 
            T0.metric_id, 
            T1.metric_id
       FROM `personal_aggregates` AS T0
  LEFT JOIN `qrs_metrics` AS T1 
         ON T0.metric_id = T1.qrs_metric_id
      WHERE T0.user_id = 1 AND 
            T0.duration = '1' AND 
            T0.category_id IN (1,2,3,4) AND 
            T0.timestamp >= 'period_duration'
   GROUP BY DATE(T0.timestamp)";
```

I am trying to join the tables on the columns metric_id and qrs_metric_id. However I get no results from the above query. When I loop through the result in PHP and check any of the variables, for example `$result['T0.metric_id']`, I get `Undefined index: T0.metric_id`

If anyone can shed any light on this I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Please format your SQL code next time. Nobody is willing to read a giant line of doom.

Comment: Do you get results if you run the query directly in MySQL (workbench or command line)?

Comment: The join is correct, it's the PHP that's behaving unpleasantly here.  I suggest to add column aliases to your query: `SELECT T0.metric_id as t0_metric_id, T1.metric_id as t1_metric_id,...` and then in PHP read them as `$row['t0_metric_id']` and `$row['t1_metric_id']`

Comment: @Trent Yes I do, i have tried via phpMyAdmin

Comment: What are the table structures?  (it seems personal_aggregates doesn't have a column for metric_Id?  (perhaps you need to group by T0.metric_Id, and T1.metric_ID as well) and alias t0 & t1.metric_Ids..

Comment: You'll need to add T0.metric_id and T1.metric_id to you GROUP BY list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE(T0.timestamp), SUM(T0.total_responses), SUM(T0.responses),
               T0.metric_id AS metric0, T1.metric_id AS metric1
        FROM `personal_aggregates` AS T0
        LEFT JOIN `qrs_metrics` AS T1 ON T0.metric_id = T1.qrs_metric_id
        WHERE T0.user_id = 1 AND T0.duration = '1'
        AND T0.category_id IN (1,2,3,4)
        AND T0.timestamp >= 'period_duration'
        GROUP BY DATE(T0.timestamp)";
```

you can now make a difference by using this:

```
echo $row['metric0'];
echo $row['metric1'];
```

Comment: Brilliant, spot on. Marking this as answer as answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
$query = "SELECT 
                DATE(T0.timestamp) AS T0timestamp, 
                SUM(T0.total_responses) AS total_responses, 
                SUM(T0.responses) AS responses,
                T0.metric_id, 
                T1.metric_id AS metric_id_2
        FROM `personal_aggregates` AS T0
```

And accessed like

```
$result['metric_id'];
$result['metric_id_2'];
$result['T0timestamp'];
$result['total_responses'];
```

Exclude the table alias from the associative array access e.g. "T0.XXX" is wrong. You can only do that in the SQL

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to add some aliases to your selected columns

```
SELECT DATE(T0.timestamp) as tstamp, SUM(T0.total_responses) as responses...
```

and refer to the columns by alias:

```
$result['tstamp']
```

or you can refer to the columns by numeric index:

```
$result[0]
```